# Must a ratio be made for trading with candlestick patterns?

Tags: technical-analysis

I am trying to figure out how to trade properly with candlestick patterns. After I set up the prices and get the results, I see for every candle there are many options with a negative or positive value. Before the candles, I calculated the William %R oscillator with the thought that it will help me make a decision, before generating the last candle that can last up to 5/15 minutes e.g. Or it can be any other technical analysis besides candles to close or open a position faster.

I can identify what a candlestick type is if this is a signal, warning, or indecision. And with the technical analysis after the signal to observe when the price it reverts. Is this a proper way to do it? (observing the images at the end seems to be wrong, but it's only on view in reality from there the calculations for candles and oscillators begin. Because they are the last / first prices)

Candlestick pattern functions:

[image: Candlestick pattern functions]

Trend lines:

[image: Trend lines]

Comment: There's an entire industry built on the premise that you can trade your way to success with technical analysis. Books, seminars, courses. After a few months/years of this, you'll be able to converse fluently with other speakers of the language. Will you have large profits? Don't count on it. And FWIW, the Williams %R oscillator is just an inverted Stochastic indicator and just as useless. All TA indicators are a reflection of past price and/or volume movement and they predict nothing going forward.  It's like looking in the rear view mirror and expecting that to tell you where you are going.

Comment: Thanks @BobBaerker. Very nice description you have made, lol. This is the purpose of the Indicator, to look back if the price was higher or lower, all after the signal (can be another candle in the same direction to not miss it) and to close the position after that.

Comment: I'm quite aware of how these indicators to work. Draw an arbitrary line at 20% and 80% consider the security overbought or oversold whenever the signal goes above 80 or below 20. If you pick a longer number of days (or whatever time period you're looking at), often, the OB or OS security will no longer be OB or OS. LOL. And then there are all of the useless whipsaws. If you really want some insight into its performance, backtest the signal and remove the biased eye from the equation. One day you'll realize the shortcomings in this and you'll move on to something more substantial. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Indeed a test will be made shortly to remove all biases. Only with the TA there is 80% loss 20% win.